# How to make an alias to a query in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a long query and I'm looking for a way to simplify it for the executer.

For example, I have this query:

```
select function_1(r_set) from (select collect_set(records) as r_set from (select function_2(<column_name>) as records from <table_name>) as record_t) as record_set_t;
```

- function_1 and function_2 are custom UDFs.

Since everything besides the table name and column name are constant, Is it possible to define some kind of alias or procedure to a query, with column name and table name as a parameter?
or even wrap it somehow with shorter execution command?

I look for something like:

```
# set alias for long query somehow 
    set MyQueryAlias = select function_1(r_set) from (select collect_set(records) as r_set from (select function_2(<column_name>) as records from <table_name>) as record_t) as record_set_t;

# execute the query with table name and column name as a parameter 
    exec MyQueryAlias <table_name> <column_name>
```

My purpose is to make it easy for other users to use the saved query on different tables and columns.

Comment: use parameters: set hivevar:tablename=mytable; select * from ${hivevar:tablename};

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin, I edited the question a bit, as it wasn't clear.
Ideally I would like a way to shorter the query. 
So when I write  "exec MyQuery MyTable MyColumn "
(or any other format)
it will actually execute  "select function_1(r_set) from (select collect_set(records) as r_set from (select function_2(MyColumn) as records from MyTable) as record_t) as record_set_t;"

Comment: You can pass part of query (for example table name) as a parameter using hivevar or hiveconf variables. Such variables are resolved before query parsing, so you can parametrize any part of query, even the whole query. Also you can use macros, nothing else. Hive SQL is not a procedural language

Comment: to clarify, I dont need to set the table name as parameter, this will be up to the user that will execute the query – only to simplify the long query.
I liked the macro idea, although it seems it's not built for what I want to do. I tried: 'CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO my_macro(tableName string, columnName string) select function_1(r_set) from (select collect_set(records) as r_set from (select function_2(columnName) as records from tableName) as record_t) as record_set_t;"'  that resulting a 'FAILED: ParseException line 2:21 missing EOF at 'as' near ')''